# Flutter app crashs and restart from splash screen when using camera function

Tags: flutter, camera, crash, runtime-error, crop

I want to click an image and send it to the server. the code works well if we are using `gallery function` but fails to work when it is swap by `camera function`.

I am able to open the camera, click the image and after this select if correct or wrong.

after this step the app crash. Next to this step, image needs to be sent to the cropping screen.

here is the code:

```
Future getImage() async {
    // var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      var _image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
      sourcePath: _image.path,
      aspectRatioPresets: [
        CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
      ],
      androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
          toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
          toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
          initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
          lockAspectRatio: false),
      iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
        minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
      )
    );
    if (_pickInProgress) {
        return;
    }
      _pickInProgress = true;
      if (_image != null) {
        setState(() {
          _newAvatar = croppedFile;
        });
      }
      _pickInProgress = false;
  }
```

in `Android Studio` I have the bellow log when filter is used with keyword `flutter`:

```
2020-02-19 17:51:48.404 10631-10631/in.x.demo D/FlutterActivity: Using the launch theme as normal theme.
2020-02-19 17:51:48.413 10631-10631/in.x.demo D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate: Setting up FlutterEngine.
2020-02-19 17:51:48.413 10631-10631/in.x.demo D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate: No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
2020-02-19 17:51:48.795 10631-10701/in.x.demo I/flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:38436/ayKKbiBs2ts=/
2020-02-19 17:51:49.031 10631-10631/in.x.demo D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate: Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
2020-02-19 17:51:49.112 10631-10631/in.x.demo D/FlutterView: Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@178fa3d
2020-02-19 17:51:49.142 10631-10631/in.x.demo D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate: Executing Dart entrypoint: main, and sending initial route: /
2020-02-19 17:51:51.013 10631-10673/in.x.demo E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'contains' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: contains("access_token")
    #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
    #1      _SplashScreenState.didChangeDependencies (package:demo/screens/common/splash_screen.dart:58:28)
    #2      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)
    #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
    #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
    #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
    #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
    #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
    #8      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:607:9)
    #9      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
    #10     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:554:7)
    #11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
    #12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
    #13     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
    #14     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
    #15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
    #16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
2020-02-19 17:51:51.015 10631-10673/in.x.demo I/flutter: genesis started
2020-02-19 17:51:51.106 10631-10673/in.x.demo I/flutter: device ID: ee44d5897844a106
2020-02-19 17:51:52.078 10631-10673/in.x.demo I/flutter: genesis final completed
2020-02-19 17:51:52.102 10631-10673/in.x.demo I/flutter: genesis api called !
2020-02-19 17:51:52.102 10631-10673/in.x.demo I/flutter: hasToken true
2020-02-19 17:51:53.085 10631-10673/in.x.demo E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()
    #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
    #1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1492:19)
    #2      _SplashScreenState.didChangeDependencies.<anonymous closure> (package:demo/screens/common/splash_screen.dart:54:23)
    #3      new Future.delayed.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:316:39)
    #4      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1122:38)
    #5      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
    #6      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
    #7      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
    #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
    #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
    #10     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:949:23)
    #11     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:23:15)
    #12     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:384:19)
    #13     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)
    #14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)


`
```

Comment: have you add permission?

Comment: @Naeem yes added the permission.

Comment: I had the exact issue, but in my case I had to open the camera from the initState(), but after trying similar github issues, I tried to use the WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback();
src: https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/04/addpostframecallback/

And couldn't observe the issue again, let us know, if you got through this!

Comment: @princeoo7 Did you solve this error? I have same problem

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your object is null when call '.contains('access_token')'
2. Maybe your context is null when called 'navigator.of'